# update price based on current date vs field_date_event

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a **content-type** = **Event**; and a **product-type** = **Registration**.

A visitor registers (submits this as an order) to an Event and is sent to their cart to process their payment. I need to **modify the price of Registration based on a date range related to the actual Event date**.

I want to compare **field_date_event** (from the content-type), to the **current system date** so I can do a Data comparison in Rules. **How do I do this?**

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do I set up a rule to compare the system date to a field?